# Custom tool error: Could not load generator "MvcView"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

I'm using the Razor Single File Generator VS extension to pre-compile my views into my class library. At least I'm trying to. I've followed the instructions and when I run the custom tool, I get this error:

```
Custom tool error: Could not load generator "MvcView".
```

I've downloaded the source code for the extension and the sample projects within exhibit the same behavior. I've uninstalled and re-installed the extension, no luck. I restarted VS (all instances) after install/uninstall, too.

#### The View

```
@* Generator: MvcView *@

@model MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/DefaultLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with the latest version (0.6).